# How to connect AWS Lambda Quarkus app to DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, connection, quarkus

I'm currently learning the AWS stack and have encountered a problem with the connection between the Quarkus application and the DynamoDB database. I'm using CDK to describe the stack and it looks as follows:

[image: Application stack]

I'm using [DynamoDB Client](https://quarkiverse.github.io/quarkiverse-docs/quarkus-amazon-services/dev/amazon-dynamodb.html#_configuring_dynamodb_clients) in Quarkus app and seems I don't fully understand how to provide credentials for Quarkus. Can someone direct me about the best practices? Should I use AWS SSM to provide it? Put them directly? Use IAM role? And what about connection URL? Maybe someone knows how to make such connection. Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DynamoDB is not like your typical database, it uses HTTPs methods to interact with it. Here is my suggestions:

1. Create DynamoDB permissions in your [Lambda's ExecutionRole](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-intro-execution-role.html)
2. Once you have a role assigned to the Lambda, your client should resolve the credentials without the need to explicitly set it, defined [here](https://quarkiverse.github.io/quarkiverse-docs/quarkus-amazon-services/dev/amazon-dynamodb.html#quarkus-amazon-dynamodb_quarkus.dynamodb.aws.credentials.type)
3. Set the [region in your client](https://quarkiverse.github.io/quarkiverse-docs/quarkus-amazon-services/dev/amazon-dynamodb.html#quarkus-amazon-dynamodb_quarkus.dynamodb.aws.region), now the client will be able to understand the endpoint without needing to explicitly set it.

Comment: I set these settings `quarkus.dynamodb.aws.region=us-east-1 quarkus.dynamodb.aws.credentials.type=default` and added a Role to Lambda with inline policy containing actions: `"dynamodb:BatchGetItem","dynamodb:BatchWriteItem", "dynamodb:GetItem", "dynamodb:PutItem", "dynamodb:Query", "dynamodb:Scan", "dynamodb:UpdateItem"` what I get when calling an endpoint is `Internal server error`. Am I missing something?

Comment: Internal server error is not caused by permissions. You're likely sending an incomplete response back through API Gateway.

Comment: I created a logs for API Gateway and I found that the application was throwing a timeout exception. To prevent this I increased timeout response and give it more memory. And suddenly it started to work. Thanks for your help.